# Unable to Allocate Memory for an Array with Size

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm an NLP noob working on a project, and I need to calculate the accuracy for a few different methods; however, I keep getting memory errors when running the code. For example, I keep getting "Unable to allocate 14.2 GiB for an array with shape (38045, 50000) and data type float64", even though I cast to a uint8 data type and messed with the Windows advanced settings to change the memory allocation. My code is below.

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
import sklearn.feature_extraction.text
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv ('amprocessed.csv')
labels = df.iloc[:, 0]
import sklearn.model_selection
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=50000, dtype="uint8")
#vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = (vectorizer.fit_transform(df["Source"]).toarray()).astype(dtype="uint8")

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler() 
xscale = scaler.fit_transform(X).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

from sklearn import svm
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(xscale, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear') # Linear Kernel

clf.fit(x_train, y_train).astype(dtype=np.uint8)

y_pred = clf.predict(x_test)

from sklearn import metrics
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: In one place you use `dtype=np.uint8` but in other places it's `dtype="uint8"`. I think the latter ones are supposed to be the numpy type object like the first one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are transforming the output of `CountVectorizer` into an `np.array`. `CountVectorizer` output a sparse matrix `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` which is an efficient way to store such data.

Instead of having for each document a `np.array` of shape `(50000,0)` with almost all value equal to 0 and very few equal 1, Sparse Matrix will only reference the value not equal to `0`. This will greatly reduce the memory footprint as shown in this example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import numpy as np
import sys

X = np.zeros((100_000))
X[0] = 1
print(f'size (bytes) of np.array {sys.getsizeof(X)}')
X_sparse = csr_matrix(X)
print(f'size (bytes) of Sparse Matrix {sys.getsizeof(X_sparse)}')
```

Outputs:

```
size (bytes) of np.array 800104
size (bytes) of Sparse Matrix 48
```

Therefore you should modify your preprocessing code with:

```
X = (vectorizer.fit_transform(df["Source"]).toarray())
```

In addition to that, the fit function should be simply written as follow:

```
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```